# Find first instance and copy to another dataframe using R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of people by name - they are all unique entries.
I have a second dataframe of payments some of these people have made with the date these payments were made.

What i'm trying to do is append to my unique names dataframe the date that the individual made their first payment.
Below is some sample data and the code I'm using

```
 Name   payment date
 Fred   01/01/2018
 Jim    01/01/2018
 Barney 01/01/2018
 Fred   01/03/2018
 John   01/02/2018
 Jim    01/03/2018
 Fred   01/04/2018
 John   01/04/2018
 Barney 01/02/2018
 Barney 01/03/2018
 Jim    01/05/2018
 Fred   01/06/2018
```

The names dataframe includes some people who have not made a payment, therefore when i'm doing the match I want to return an "NA" for that person so the table will look like this:

```
 Name   first payment
 Fred   01/01/2018
 Jim    01/01/2018
 Rodney NA
 Barney 01/01/2018
 John   01/02/2018
```

I've run the following code to order the payments dataframe by payment date

```
payments<-payments[order(payments$paymentdate),]
```

Then the R code I'm using to look up and match the first instance by name:

```
people$firstpayment<-payments[match
(people$Name,payments$Name,nomatch = 0,incomparables = NULL),c("paymentdate")]
```

is failing with the following R error code:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, firstpayment, value = list(paymentdate = c15247,  : 
replacement has 10288 rows, data has 14610
```

I assume this is to do with the inability to match the NAs, but I did some reading on "match" function and I thought the nomatch command would deal with this.

Thanks!

Comment: Would a `left_join(df1, df2, by = "ID")` function work here?

Comment: doesn't appear to be. I tried     people$first <- left_join(payments,people, by="Name"). it gives error     Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, first, value = list(name = c("Fred",  : 
  replacement has 268890 rows, data has 14610

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the dataframe of payments (I will call it "second_dataframe") to have only first payment by one person and than merge the two tables by Name:

```
library(dplyr)

# Filter
second_dataframe <- second_dataframe %>% group_by(Name) %>% summarise(`first payment`=min(`payment date`))

#Merge
merge(first_dataframe, second_dataframe, by="Name", all=TRUE)
```

Comment: That seems to work - thanks. I've changed "max" to "min" to get the first but presumably if I wanted to get the last i'd use max?  Does this negate the need to sort the dataframe by the date variable first?

Comment: True, it should have been "min". Plus, I have added "all=TRUE" to merge function (than it will leave all NAs). And yes, you don't need to sort dataframe by the date variable first.